# Warning while executing powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

This is the continuation of this question i have asked in this SE [How to run a PowerShell script from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-using-batch-file/19335763) .I have used powershell to execute this command

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2"
Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -Action { invoke-item "C:\Program Files\abc.exe"}
```

I have succesfully executed the powersell script but i am getting this warning.
[image]

Can you tell me how can i rectify this issue

Comment: have you tried explicitly declaring which columns you want to display?

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the command to `Format-List` or try `Format-Table -Auto`:

```
Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -Action { invoke-item "C:\Program Files\abc.exe"} | Format-List
```

or

```
Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -Action { invoke-item "C:\Program Files\abc.exe"} | Format-Table -Auto
```

Comment: both query didn't work the job state is "not started"

Comment: You could also try resizing the console to 120 chars wide. :-)

Comment: i am extremely sorry but i am new to powershell and i dont understand by resizing the console? Using your above script i got this message http://i43.tinypic.com/23t087n.png