# running a PowerShell script with parameters from a batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am working on a batch script to read in some parameters and start a PowerShell script, which needs the typed in parameters.

What I have done so far:

```
Set /p arg1 = Type in a name for the  data: 

Set /p arg2 = Type in the directory of the project: 

Set /p arg3 = Type in the programming language : 

Set /p arg4 = Type in a version for the metric data: 

SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%Metrics.ps1

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%' 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3' 'arg4'";
```

Unfortunally the PowerShell script doesn't accept the parameters.

Comment: This question is already answered at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-a-batch-file). I would really follow the link of @deadlydog. His [blog](http://blog.danskingdom.com/allow-others-to-run-your-powershell-scripts-from-a-batch-file-they-will-love-you-for-it/) is very good.

Comment: thanks, i will keep it in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "%PowerShellScriptPath%" %arg1% %arg2% ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable names have a trailing space ("whatever<space>"). Lose the space before and after the equals sign:

```
Set /p arg1=Type in a name for the  data: 
Set /p arg2=Type in the directory of the project: 
Set /p arg3=Type in the programming language : 
Set /p arg4=Type in a version for the metric data:
```

Comment: Hardly my answer now?