# How can I find the length of the first line of a file in batch or powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have to read each file in a folder and determine the length of the first line of each, then do something depending on whether or not that length is what is should be in a table. I can loop through each file in batch and have %%f as the file, but how do I get that length and assign it to a variable?

If there is a way to do this in Powershell using a batch file, that would help, but I would need to know how to call the Powershell from the batch file also.

Comment: You'd better do that in "true" Powershell style, using a Powershell script. It can do a `Get-Content $file` and parse that, it can do `Get-ChildItem` aka `dir` to get the list of files, and of course it can loop via `foreach ($file in $files)`. Variables are also supported, of course, all that starts with a dollar sign is a variable (set or unset). And to call Powershell you can do `powershell -command "powershell commands; more commands; last command"`.

Answer (score 1):

The simple PowerShell code would look something like this:

```
param($path)
Get-ChildItem $path -File | 
    Select FullName,@{Label="1stLineLength";Expression={(Get-Content $_.FullName -First 1).Length}}
```

So the first argument will be taken as the path of the script. Then to call it from batch I borrow the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19335763/3829407).

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File m:\Scripts\firstlinelength.ps1 "C:\temp"
```

That will get output like this on console.

```
FullName                              1stLineLength
--------                              -------------
C:\Users\mcameron\CleansedBigFile.txt             4
```

This code assumes that you have at least PowerShell v3.0 for the `-First` and `-File` parameter and switch. I would like to think that most batch code can be converted easily to a PowerShell equivalent so if your environment allows you consider converting to the powerful PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your question is pretty vague (what table?). But in general, you don't need a batch file at all. PowerShell example:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | ForEach-Object {
  $firstLineLength = (Get-Content $_ | Select-Object -First 1).Length
  if ( $firstLineLength -gt $whateverFromTable ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that the `-File` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` doesn't exist before PowerShell v3. For PowerShell v2 and below, you would replace `Get-ChildItem -File` with `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }`.