# Error thrown when trying to create shortcuts with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am not at all versed in PowerShell, but I am trying to use it nonetheless. I am working to automate an OS build for my IT department and I have almost everything done except for the creation of shortcuts. I found this topic: [How to run a PowerShell script from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-a-batch-file) that told me how I could use PowerShell to do this.

When I run this command (saving to the default user profile's desktop) It throws an error.

---

POWERSHELL:

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell

$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Default\Desktop\ReadMe.lnk")

$Shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\ReadMe.htm"

$Shortcut.Save()
```

---

COMMAND:

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "C:\Users\trw68319\Desktop\Powershell Shortcuts.ps1"
```

---

[image]

---

I suspect this is due to the fact that the default user is a hidden directory (I tried this with a different directory and it worked). Could anyone please tell me if it is possible to complete this task while saving to the default (hidden) user directory?

Thanks

Comment: Do you run command with admin rights?

Comment: Wow. That did it. I don't know why I didn't try from an elevated command prompt earlier. Thank you for the simple fix.

Comment: In the future do not post a link to a screen shot of the error. Please copy the error text and paste into your question as text.