# "Al.exe could not be found" when build 4.0 projects in MSBuild with resource files

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, msbuild

I have a project developed in 4.0 framework and it is working fine when running with visual studio. But when i execute the same project with MSBuild in command prompt , the project not getting build which shows error of "Al.exe is not found"

```
"C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\Msbuild.exe"
```

**The above issue occurs only if the project contains resource files and build with msbuild through command prompt.**

The msbuild command runs through process start methods using the below code,

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

psi.FileName = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Msbuild.exe";

psi.Arguments = "D:\Samples\Localization\cs\LocalizationDemo_2010.csproj" /p:Configuration=Release /nologo /noconlog /fileLogger /fileloggerparameters:logfile="D:\Samples\Localization\cs\build.log";

Process p = Process.Start(psi);
```

Please anyone help me if you have any ideas about this.

Regards,

Amal Raj

Comment: Show the entire error message please

Comment: @OfirW error MSB3086: Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed

Comment: Did you install the Windows SDK ? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6B6C21D2-2006-4AFA-9702-529FA782D63B&displaylang=en

Comment: i have installed all .net frame work versions upto 4.6 . i could not find windows sdk for windows 7 and 4.0

Comment: You're on windows 8? check this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk

Comment: i am windows 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133802/discussion-between-ofirw-and-amal).

Comment: Do you run this from a developer command prompt?

Comment: @stijn - Yes, i run the project in command prompt with msbuild

Comment: edited the question, as the failure occurs only for projects with resource files in msbuild execution

Comment: If you run the command prompt you shouldn't specify the full path to msbuild, it should be in the search path? Idem for al.exe. If you start the correct VS command prompt and ttype `al` it should run AL. Does it? Also your edit raises a new question: does it work if you run msbuild /path/to/project directly instead of programmatically?

Comment: @stijn - I think this issue is not with path or arguments. This issue occurs only in machine installed with VS2017 only. And the same project works fine in machine installed with VS2010, VS2012, VS2013, VS2015

Comment: Please refer to the error log C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2863,5): error MSB3086: Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". 
Could anyone please let me know, how to register the 8.0A  with Al.exe as recommened?

Comment: Here's a stupid tip: I had the exact same issue, but with .NET 2.0 projects. I was missing the Individual Component ".NET Framework 3.5 development tools" in the VS setup. Installing them fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your command line invocation of MSBuild uses the same set of build assemblies that your version of Visual Studio uses. You did not specify what version of Visual Studio you are using, but in any case this should set you in the right direction:

1. In Visual Studio, set the following to *Diagnostic*: Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->"MSBuild project build output verbosity".
2. Build the project and then search the Output window's Build pane for `MSBuildToolsPath`.
3. Use that property's value (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin`) as the path to `msbuild.exe` when you build from the command line.

**EDIT**
Now that we know you are using VS 2017 RC, and with credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40702534/704808, search for `msbuild.exe` under `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\`.

Comment: I am using VS2017 RC

Comment: What should i do after Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->"MSBuild project build output verbosity". Could not find the MSBuildToolsPath in build pane of Output window ?

Comment: There is no 14.0 folder exists under msbuild for machine installed with VS2017 alone.

Comment: I know:). Just do a recursive search for msbuild.exe under the path I specified in my edit at the bottom of my answer.