# MSB3086: Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath

Tags: c#, .net, windows, msbuild

When executing projects with resource files through msbuild in a machine installed with VS2017 RC, the projects didn't gets compiled successfully. It shows the below error,

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2863,5): error MSB3086: Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed**

And i have checked that "Al.exe" is not found under 8.0A folder as the folder structure is like below,

[image]

Please let me how to solve the issue?
Please let me know, how to register the files under 8.0A folders with registries.

Regards,
Amal Raj

Comment: same question (not answered though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803829/al-exe-could-not-be-found-when-build-4-0-projects-in-msbuild-with-resource-fil

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Al.exe could not be found" when build 4.0 projects in MSBuild with resource files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41803829/al-exe-could-not-be-found-when-build-4-0-projects-in-msbuild-with-resource-fil)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by Installing the Windows SDK for Windows 8