# msbuild builderror for .net standard library

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community on a Windows 10 box.

When I add a .net standard library (just the default code) to my solution the solution builds just fine in Visual studio 2017.

But when I try to build the solution using 
&'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\msbuild.exe' C:_Sources\MySolution\MyProject\MyProject.csproj

I get a build error:

> error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the
>   MSBuild XML namespace. If t he project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
>   format, please add
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>    element. If the pro ject has been authored in the old 1.0 or
>   1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format

It looks similar to [this bugreport](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1550) but I'm on windows so this does not seem to apply to me.

the csproj file contents:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried upgrading it to netstandard1.6 but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out I was using the wrong msbuild version.

The msbuild file resides in a different location now with vs2017

[How do I call Visual Studio 2017 RC's version of MSBuild from a BAT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694598/how-do-i-call-visual-studio-2017-rcs-version-of-msbuild-from-a-bat-file)