# MSBuild.exe not found, cmd.exe

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I recently installed Visual Studio 2017, shouldn't MSBuild.exe come with it? One of bash scripts is calling it, but can't find anything.

Here is the part of build.bat that yields error (you can see the whole file [here](https://github.com/mpc-hc/mpc-hc/blob/develop/build.bat))

```
MSBuild.exe mpc-hc.sln %MSBUILD_SWITCHES%^
 /target:%BUILDTYPE% /property:Configuration="%BUILDCFG% Filter";Platform=%1^
 /flp1:LogFile=%LOG_DIR%\filters_errors_%BUILDCFG%_%1.log;errorsonly;Verbosity=diagnostic^
 /flp2:LogFile=%LOG_DIR%\filters_warnings_%BUILDCFG%_%1.log;warningsonly;Verbosity=diagnostic
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  CALL "%COMMON%" :SubMsg "ERROR" "mpc-hc.sln %BUILDCFG% Filter %1 - Compilation failed!"
  EXIT /B
) ELSE (
  CALL "%COMMON%" :SubMsg "INFO" "mpc-hc.sln %BUILDCFG% Filter %1 compiled successfully"
)
```

Comment: Have you searched for the file?

Comment: Your bash script isn't calling it.  Proof: examining your question I see no bash script calling it.

Comment: @Stefan There is one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64 and one in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin , what's the difference between them?

Comment: [edit] in the relevant parts of the script

Comment: Has it changed [since the beta version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694598/how-do-i-call-visual-studio-2017-rcs-version-of-msbuild-from-a-bat-file)?

Comment: @Will edited, here

Comment: It is hard to find back in VS2017.  You must use the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2017" to ensure the PATH is set correctly.  You did not mention using it so probably what you forgot to do.

Comment: @HansPassant launching "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" with "where msbuild" showed one in `Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` and one in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe` . I guess I'll use first one, and hope for the best.

Comment: Not having to guess is the point of using it.  Just run you .bat file as-is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `vswhere` <sup>1</sup> which comes with `Visual Studio 2017`.
It is located in `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"`.

The part of the path to `MSBuild.exe` is then retrived by `vswhere -nologo -latest -property installationPath`, which results e.g., in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community`.
Based on the msbuild Version you want to use you can now guess the rest of the path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\**VERSION**\Bin\MSBuild.exe

where **VERSION** is e.g., `15.0` for Version `installationVersion: 15.3.26730.12`as ouputed by `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property installationVersion`.

<sup>1</sup> See [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere)