# What's the difference between Bin/MSBuild.exe and Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I [was looking for MSBuild.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223916/msbuild-exe-not-found-cmd-exe), and I found it in two slightly different places:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
```

What's the difference between them and which should I use?

Comment: Microsoft generally makes build tools available both in their 32-bit and their 64-bit version.  Where the 64-bit version can be expected to handle much larger build jobs.  Sometimes that is useful, the C++ compiler for example.  Sometimes it makes no sense because the tool could not possibly ever run out of memory.  Like MSBuild.  A corner-case is the build tool itself having to load a 64-bit custom build DLL.   Technically possible for MSBuild.  Only technically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What's the difference between them?

The MSBuild.exe has two versions, 32-bit and 64-bit.

**On 32-bit machines**, the MSBuild.exe exists in the path: `C:\Program Files\..\..\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

**On 64-bit machines**, there are two version of MSBuild.exe tool. The 32-bit tools will be under: `Bin\MSBuild.exe` and the 64-bit tools under: `Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe`

If you want to know some differences between these two versions, you can refer to the blog: [Building on Cross targeting scenarios and 64-bit MSBuild](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/05/07/building-on-cross-targeting-scenarios-and-64-bit-msbuild/).

> which should I use?

To answer this question, you should to know the differences between 32-bit program and 64-bit program. You can refer [this document](http://sedodream.com/2009/08/21/MSBuildBuilding64BitVersus32Bit.aspx) for detail.

> 1. If the assembly is configured for Any CPU then it will run as x64 on a 64-bit machine and as x86 on a 32-bit machine.
> 2. If the assembly is configured for x86 then it will run as WOW64 on a 64-bit machine (i.e. a 32-bit process) and as x86 on a 32-bit
>      machine.
> 3. If the assembly is configured for x64 then it will run as x64 on a 64-bit machine and will fail to run on a 32-bit machine

So **you should use Bin/MSBuild.exe**, which can be run on 64-bit machine and as x86 on a 32-bit.

Besides, Visual Studio build is equivalent to running 32-bit MSBuild.