# Powershell file won't work with double-click

Tags: powershell

I have a simple powershell file that removes some files with a particular name. I can double-click to run the file which briefly shows the powershell window but it doesn't work. It works if I open a non-admin powershell window and dot-source it or run from the ISE. The file is not blocked and I created it on my local computer. If I add "Pause" to the beginning of the file it still crashes without doing anything which tells me this isn't a problem with the script and is more that Powershell has a problem with me running the script.

Comment: This is not surprising. By default it is not possible to run a PowerShell script by double-clicking on it.

Comment: you can do it with a batch .bat file. have a see on http://stackoverflow.com/a/19335763/259025