# Run PowerShell code from batch file

Tags: powershell

Very simple code:

```
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Command Prompt.lnk")
$bytes[0x15] = $bytes[0x15] -bor 0x20
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Command Prompt.lnk", $bytes)
```

It makes the shortcut to be run as Administrator.
I look through some examples in stackoverflow, but nothing works. And I'd like to write it not in a single line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a PowerShell script from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-a-batch-file)

Comment: Save it as a Powershell Script and see the answer in the link above.

Comment: I do not want to use ps1 file; batch file only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@findstr /v "^@f.*&" "%~f0" | powershell -&goto eof
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Command Prompt.lnk")
$bytes[0x15] = $bytes[0x15] -bor 0x20
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Command Prompt.lnk", $bytes)
```