# Write to a file encoded in USC-2 LE BOM, batch script

Tags: batch-file, unicode, encoding

I want to be able to create an *.rdp file from a bat file, however I just noticed that rdp files are actually encoded as `USC-2 LE BOM`, while my bat is producing a `UTF-8` file, here's what I do:

```
@echo off
> file.rdp (
echo screen mode id:i:2
... bunch of echoes
echo lastparam:: )
```

This produces what I expected but is encoded in `UTF-8`, is there a way to either:

- Create a file, set its encoding and then apend to it?
- Produce the output from `>` encoded in `USC-2 LE BOM` directly to a file?
- Encode the `UTF-8` file into `USC-2 LE BOM` within the same bat file?

I want to write this and other files using a bat so I can set Read-only permissions to the generated file and cannot think of any other alternative. This way, I'll be able to deploy a bunch of preconfigured read-only rdp files.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [LotPigs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56068054/7369171) and [this underrated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54069584/7369171) I was able to use powershell to change the encoding, wanted to share how I was able to include the powershell encoding within the batch

```
@echo off
> utf8file ( ... )
ECHO Get-Content utf8file ^> utf16.rdp > powerShellScript.ps1
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File powerShellScript.ps1
```

Comment: Could you create a file containing just your BOM, then copy that file to your desired destination file and append data using `>>`?

Comment: Consider Powershell?

Comment: @Magoo Does not work, `>>` spits out UTF-8 data, so file ends up with lots of giberish, chinese chars mostly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by montonero use powershell with default UTF16LE encoding

```
> Get-Content .\UTF16LEBOM.ps1
@"
screen mode id:i:2
... bunch of echoes
lastparam::
"@ > file.rdp
```

---

```
> hex .\file.rdp

Detected Byte Order Mark (BOM) : UTF16LE

Blk00000: File : .\file.rdp
HexOffs.:_+0_+1_+2_+3__+4_+5_+6_+7__+8_+9_+A_+B__+C_+D_+E_+F__----____----____
00000000: FF FE 73 00  63 00 72 00  65 00 65 00  6E 00 20 00  ..s.c.r.e.e.n. .
00000010: 6D 00 6F 00  64 00 65 00  20 00 69 00  64 00 3A 00  m.o.d.e. .i.d.:.
00000020: 69 00 3A 00  32 00 0D 00  0A 00 2E 00  2E 00 2E 00  i.:.2...........
00000030: 20 00 62 00  75 00 6E 00  63 00 68 00  20 00 6F 00   .b.u.n.c.h. .o.
00000040: 66 00 20 00  65 00 63 00  68 00 6F 00  65 00 73 00  f. .e.c.h.o.e.s.
00000050: 0D 00 0A 00  6C 00 61 00  73 00 74 00  70 00 61 00  ....l.a.s.t.p.a.
00000060: 72 00 61 00  6D 00 3A 00  3A 00 0D 00  0A 00        r.a.m.:.:.....
```

Comment: so powerful... it does lack the old school swag of a simple bat but i'll try it.

Comment: Well, the lower output is in fact generated by an old vbscript/batch hybrid executed in powershell console ;-)

Comment: Maybe, but there's just something about them scripts that make me feel dirty

Comment: Just edited to go back to the old school swag within a single batch... couldn't have done it without you, thanks!