# Control of mouse settings from command line in Windows 7

Tags: windows, mouse

Because of a disability I like to be able to switch from using a right-hand mouse to a left-hand mouse, and back again, every half-hour or so. Doing this from the control panel is slower than I would like. Although I can open the mouse settings controller using `main.cpl` on the command line or in a `.bat` file, I'd like to to able to do the entire left-right switch using a batch file. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the code to the PS1 file and run it with Powershell:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null

$SwapButtons = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SwapMouseButton(bool swap);
'@ -Name "NativeMethods" -Namespace "PInvoke" -PassThru

[bool]$returnValue = $SwapButtons::SwapMouseButton(!([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::MouseButtonsSwapped))
```

Comment: And for details on how to run the PS1 file from a batch file see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-a-batch-file