# How to run powershell inside BAT file from the same directory

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch script to run powershell, how to set path to ps1 file if this file is in the same folder as executing BAT file? I use this but not working.

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""./Reboot.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}";
```

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-a-batch-file

Comment: I have changed file, still not works       `PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ""./Reboot.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}";`   Reboot.bat and Reboot.ps1 are in the same folder.

Comment: You don't need `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` for the `-Command`, only for the `-File`. Also you're on Windows, so use the correct path separator, `.\Reboot.ps1` not `./Reboot.ps1`.

Answer (score 1):

Read `call /?` and [Links relative to the Batch Script](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

> You can get the pathname of the batch script itself with `%0`,
>   parameter extensions can be applied to this so `%~dp0` will return the
>   Drive and Path to the batch script.

Use `… -File ""%~dp0Reboot.ps1"" …` (note that `%~dp0` *includes* a trailing backslash!)

Answer (score 0):

With `./Reboot.ps` you address the current working directory. What you need is the directory of the BAT file. Use `%~d0%~p0/Reboot.ps` instead.

An alternative could be to temporary set the working directory to the BAT's directory:

```
pushd %~d0%~p%"
rem run script with ./Reboot.ps1
popd
```

Obviously, if your script "Reboot.ps1" actually reboots the PC, you can skip the popd.